# iOS Facebook access Token and expirationDate NULL?

Tags: ios

```
// Check and retrieve authorization information
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([defaults objectForKey:ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY] && [defaults objectForKey:EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY]) {
    self.facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY];
    self.facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY];
}
```

This code is from Facebook iOS SDK demoCode,
But it can not set the self.facebook.accessToken and self.facebook.expirationDate.
NSLog is (NULL)
What do I wrong with that?